# pass by value/ reference / result

Tags: pascal

```
procedure p(x : integer); 
begin
  a := 5;
  x := x + 2; 
end
```

Write down the value of the variable a after execution of the following code:

```
a := 10;
p(a);
```

for each of the following parameter passing mechanisms:

(i) call by value. a. 7,10

(ii) call by reference. a. 12,12

(iii) call by value-result. a. 7,7

Got an exam on this next week and I have got the answers for the mock paper but I am confused to how X is assigned to a in the procedure call. help would be awesome

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the two numbers separated like a comma, such as 7, 10?

Comment: sorry. thats the answers to the question but i dont understand how it is 7, 10?

Comment: Does the teacher who writes this confusing Q actually means (i): `procedure p(x : integer); ` then (ii) `procedure p(var x : integer);` and (iii) `procedure p(out x : integer);` ? The problem is so badly exposed, it's unbelievable.

Comment: Ton prof est une grosse merde incompétente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (i) call by value

Whatever value is passed into p() is *copied* onto p()'s stack.  That *copy* is used in the body of p(), so the original value is never changed.  If `a` starts as 7 it will end as 7.

> (ii) call by reference

A reference to the original value is provided to p(), so that changes to the value that reference points to affect the original variable.  `a` will have a new value after p() returns.

If `a` starts as 12, it will end as 7 because it is first assigned the value of 5 in the body of p() and then that value is increased by 2.

> (iii) call by value-result

This is similar to call by reference, except that no alias is created between the formal and actual parameters.  [See details](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CallByValueResult).